# Adding emblems in Files?

Tags: settings, pantheon-files

Don't know if there is a way, but might even be possible to have emplems on file and folders, like nautilus, or simply *files* does not support that feature?

[Something similar to what nautilus-emblems provides](https://diolinux.com.br/2019/07/coloque-emblemas-em-pastas-do-nautilus.html); any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Files does not currently support this feature. There is this PR `https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/1189` to allow customising file icons but there is no guarantee when or if this will be accepted into master.